# ENS: Hide name when creating an auction

Tags: ens

Is it possible to hide the name in an ENS auction?

If so, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently only hash names are registered](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6diea4/ens_registar_some_names_are_hidden/di2vhxl/):

> It's the other way round, actually. All names are hidden - people are really only registering hashes.
>
> However, etherscan is able to decode and display some known names/hashes, namely those words on this rather large list. The list is made up of the top million Alexa .com domains plus an English dictionary, if I recall correctly.

So if your name is not in [lookup table from hash to name](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/ens-registrar-dapp/master/app/public/preimages.js), it will only appear as a hash.